# Why Illegal cookies are send by Browser and received by web servers (rfc 2109, 2965)?

Tags: cookies, webserver, rfc

According to RFC 2109, 2965 cookie's value can be either HTTP token or quoted string, and token can't include non-ASCII characters.

1. Cookie's RFC [2109](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2109#page-3) and [RFC2965](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2965#page-4)
2. HTTP's RFC 2068 and 2616 token definition: https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2616#page-16

However I had found that Firefox browser (3.0.6) sends cookies with utf-8 string as-is
and three web servers I tested (apache2, lighttpd, nginx) pass this string as-is to the
application.

For example, raw request from browser:

```
$ nc -l -p 8080
GET /hello HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost:8080
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (X11; U; Linux x86_64; en-US; rv:1.9.0.9) Gecko/2009050519 Firefox/2.0.0.13 (Debian-3.0.6-1)
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Language: en-us,en;q=0.5
Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate
Accept-Charset: windows-1255,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.7
Keep-Alive: 300
Connection: keep-alive
Cookie: wikipp=1234; wikipp_username=ארתיום
Cache-Control: max-age=0
```

And raw response of apache, nginx and lighttpd `HTTP_COOKIE` CGI variable:

```
wikipp=1234; wikipp_username=ארתיום
```

What do I miss?

Comment: It's the Internet.  People use the standards to flame others on usenet, not for implementing their software.

Comment: @jrockway I would understand if this was one web server, but all 3 most popular (Linux) ones?

Answer (score 3):

[RFC 2109](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2109#page-3) (Feb 1997) is obsolete and was superseded by [RFC 2965](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2965.txt) (Oct 2000), according to the [Internet Official Protocol Standards (STD 1, RFC 5000)](http://www.apps.ietf.org/rfc/rfc5000.html).

You may also be interested in a more recent [March 7, 2010 draft](http://bgp.potaroo.net/ietf/all-ids/draft-pettersen-cookie-v2-05.txt) to revise 2965.

The only definition of a **token** in 2965 is:

> informally, a sequence of non-special, non-white space characters

I wouldn't consider the entirety of UTF-8 to be disallowed by that definition - only characters that could be mistaken as control/syntax characters.

Comment: But according to new RFC the value is still token or quoted pair, so it does not solve my issue

Comment: Full quote: "The following grammar uses the notation, and tokens DIGIT (decimal digits), token (informally, a sequence of non-special, non-white space characters), and http_URL from the HTTP/1.1 specification [RFC2616] to describe their syntax." - So it is clearly that token **refers** to RFC2616 (http) and it forbids token to be non-assci

Comment: And BTW in the draft you linked to it is even more clear that token defined according ro 2616 HTTP/1.1 RFC

Comment: [rfc6265](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc6265) is latest now.

Answer (score 2):

[RFC 2965](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2965) has been obsoleted by [RFC 6265](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6265). According to this rfc:

The cookie name has to be a token, which consists of printable ascii chars without
( ) < > @ ,; : \ " / [ ] ? = { } SPACE TAB

The cookie value consists of printable ascii chars without SPACE " , ; \ with the possibility of being surrounded by quotes